# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available error using selenium using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, webdriver

I wrote a python script and using selenium driver. I am getting the below error:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

When I run the command: **pip install selenium**, the output is:

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in d:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in d:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from selenium)
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Can you please help to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: How are you running the script that contains `from selenium import webdriver`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in d:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages 
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in d:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from selenium) 
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available. 
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

...implies that you are using **pip v9.0.1** which is pretty ancient. You need to update **pip** to the latest available version of **`pip v19.3.1`** using the following command from the command prompt:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This is correct but the question was not how to install/upgrade pip